# React native firestore not working properly because of undefined FirebaseStorageTypes.TaskSnapshot ref

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, react-native-firebase

I have a react native app and I am trying to save a post using firestore. I am using @react-native-firebase/firestore and am using the following code:
`

```
import firebase from "@react-native-firebase/app";
import "@react-native-firebase/firestore";
import "@react-native-firebase/storage";

export const saveMediaToStorage = (media, path) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(path);

    fetch(media)
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((blob) => fileRef.put(blob))
      .then((task) => {
        task.ref.getDownloadURL();
      })
      .then((downloadUrl) => {
        // console.log(downloadUrl);
        resolve(downloadUrl);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        reject();
      });
  });
```

Response, blob and task all look good and task variable looks like this:

```
Object {
  "bytesTransferred": 2274761,
  "metadata": Object {
    "bucket": "_______.appspot.com",
    "contentDisposition": "inline; filename*=utf-8''image2",
    "contentEncoding": "identity",
    "contentType": "image/jpeg",
    "fullPath": "post/*****/****/image1",
    "generation": "1672255330334821",
    "md5Hash": "vVYL9wVo/***==",
    "metageneration": "1",
    "name": "image2",
    "size": 2274761,
    "timeCreated": "2022-12-28T19:22:10Z",
    "updated": "2022-12-28T19:22:10Z",
  },
  "state": "success",
  "totalBytes": 2274761,
}
```

I also checked firebase and see that the images are saved in the storage, but it looks like the issue is with the download url.

task.ref.getDownloadUrl() returns undefined because task.ref is undefined. Any idea what might be going wrong?

I have been working in an expo managed workflow and was using firebase/firebase-storage, and it was working fine, but I recently ejected and switched to a bare workflow in android and started using @react-native-firebase/firestore instead, which is when it broke. I added the required permissions for android (READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), but I'm wondering if I am missing something android-specific, or if the syntax is different for @react-native-firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when doing :

```
let uploadTask = ref.put(blob, {customMetadata: newMetadata});
return uploadTask
    .then((taskSnapshot) => {
        if (taskSnapshot.state === firebase.storage.TaskState.SUCCESS) {
            return taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL(); // Error
        } else {
            throw new Error("Upload error")
        }
    })
    .finally(() => {
        blob.close();
    });
```

I would get ref is undefined. I got it working by using the previously defined ref

```
let uploadTask = ref.put(blob, {customMetadata: newMetadata});
return uploadTask
    .then((taskSnapshot) => {
        if (taskSnapshot.state === firebase.storage.TaskState.SUCCESS) {
            return ref.getDownloadURL(); // Success
        } else {
            throw new Error("Upload error")
        }
    })
    .finally(() => {
        blob.close();
    });
```